Creating a time based system—hours minutes seconds
I'm currently trying Arduino C and trying to figure out the best way to convert the given added values into the correct seconds, minutes, and hours. I'm aware this needs division and modulo; it's just that I'm not sure where. How would I go about doing this?
This is my code:
void setup() {

int swimhours=0;
int swimmins=50;
int swimsecs=59;
int bikehours=2;
int bikemins=50;
int bikesecs=59;
int runhours=1;
int runmins=50;
int runsecs=59;

int totalhours=swimhours+bikehours+runhours;
int totalmins=swimmins+bikemins+runmins;
int totalsecs=swimsecs+runsecs+bikesecs;`

int completehours
int completemins
int completesecs

serial.print
}

void loop() {

}

I need the values of the above to be added (which is the total) and then I need the conversion in the complete variables.

Try keeping everything in seconds. Add the seconds, and use the division and modulo operators to get the minutes and hours (divide by 60 to get the minutes from seconds, for example).

By the way, please don't post images of text. [Edit] your question to copy-paste text (code, input, output) as text.

its just the code format, i cant wrap my head around what the code would be

int minutes = seconds / 60; and so on?

totaltime = totalsecs + (totalmins * 60) + (totalhours * 60*60);

Indeed. Do it on pen & paper first then translating it to C from there will be quite trivial.

The "trick" is to work in seconds.

These are durations, so we don't have to worry about time zones or Daylight-Savings Time, etc. Good.
First, convert everything to seconds.
swimmins += swimhours * 60u;
swimsecs += swimmins * 60u;

bikemins += bikehours * 60u;
bikesecs += bikemins * 60u;

runmins += runhours * 60u;
runsecs += runmins * 60u;

Then, find the total number of seconds.
uint16_t totalsecs = swimsecs + bikesecs + runsecs;

Finally, find convert back to hours, minutes and seconds.
uint16_t totalmins = totalsecs / 60u;
totalsecs %= 60u;

uint16_t totalhours = totalmins / 60u;
totalmins %= 60u;


Thank you a lot,i couldn't understand how to do it but this version was much easier. thank you

Also keep in mind that the OP is using dinosaur Arduino so it will have 16 bit ints. For example 106060 = overflow, undefined behavior. So "sloppy typing" with int all over the place won't do. We have to use uint16_t and u/U suffixed integer constants just as if we were doing a professional program on a real computer.

Note: uint16_t seconds good for up to about 18 hours.  It that is too narrow for OP's general use, consider long, etc.

If multiplication by 3600 can cause overflows, and you do not want to replace 16-bit int with 32-bit long, you could use repeated subtraction. It's not too bad because you are only adding three different times.
int swimhours=0;
int swimmins=50;
int swimsecs=59;
int bikehours=2;
int bikemins=50;
int bikesecs=59;
int runhours=1;
int runmins=50;
int runsecs=59;

int totalhours=swimhours+bikehours+runhours;
int totalmins=swimmins+bikemins+runmins;
int totalsecs=swimsecs+runsecs+bikesecs;

// assuming all numbers are non-negative...
while (totalsecs >= 60) {
    totalsecs -= 60;
    totalmins++;
}
while (totalmins >= 60) {
    totalmins -= 60;
    totalhours++;
}

If division by a constant is not a problem, the while loops can be replaced with division and modulo operations:
totalmins += totalsecs / 60;
totalsecs %= 60;
totalhours += totalmins / 60;
totalmins %= 60;

Or since only three times are being added, the while loops can be unrolled into a couple of if statements:
// assuming all numbers are non-negative...
if (totalsecs >= 60) {
    totalsecs -= 60;
    totalmins++;
}
if (totalsecs >= 60) {
    totalsecs -= 60;
    totalmins++;
}
if (totalmins >= 60) {
    totalmins -= 60;
    totalhours++;
}
if (totalmins >= 60) {
    totalmins -= 60;
    totalhours++;
}


I think you need something like that:
int hms_to_s(int h, int m, int s) {
    return (h * (60 * 60)) + (m * 60) + s;
}

void s_to_hms(int total_s, int* h_p, int* m_p, int* s_p) {
    if ((h_p == NULL) || (m_p == NULL) || (s_p == NULL)) {
        return;
    }

    *h_p = total_s / (60 * 60);
    *m_p = (total_s - ((*h_p) * 60 * 60)) / 60;
    *s_p = total_s - ((*m_p) * 60 + (*h_p) * 60 * 60);
}

int main()
{
    // Swim
    int swim_h = 0;
    int swim_m = 50;
    int swim_s = 59;

    // Bike
    int bike_h = 2;
    int bike_m = 50;
    int bike_s = 59;

    // Run
    int run_h = 1;
    int run_m = 50;
    int run_s = 59;

    // Total swim time (s)
    int swim_time_s = hms_to_s(swim_h, swim_m, swim_s);

    // Total bike time (s)
    int bike_time_s = hms_to_s(bike_h, bike_m, bike_s);

    // Total run time (s)
    int run_time_s  = hms_to_s(run_h,  run_m,  run_s);

    // Total (swim + bike + run) (s)
    int total_s = swim_time_s + bike_time_s + run_time_s;

    // Convert total time in seconds to hours, minutes and seconds
    int total_time_h = 0;
    int totat_time_m = 0;
    int total_time_s = 0;
    s_to_hms(total_s, &total_time_h, &totat_time_m, &total_time_s);

    // Output result
    printf("Total: %dh, %dm, %ds\n", total_time_h, totat_time_m, total_time_s);

    return 0;
}

In your case the output will be:
Total: 5h, 32m, 57s


Also keep in mind that the OP is using dinosaur Arduino so it will have 16 bit ints. For example 106060 = overflow, undefined behavior. So "sloppy typing" with int all over the place won't do. We have to use uint16_t and u/U suffixed integer constants just as if we were doing a professional program on a real computer.
